# How to get rid of main effects when coding interaction between categorical variables in patsy?

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, categorical-data, patsy

I have a problem very similar to :

[Interaction effects in patsy with patsy.dmatrices giving duplicate columns for ":" as with "+" , or "*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672466/interaction-effects-in-patsy-with-patsy-dmatrices-giving-duplicate-columns-for)

except that I have other categorical variables besides the interaction term. My formula is :

> f = 'VarDep ~  C(MoisAvantDep):C(Groupe) + C(JourSemDep) + C(MoisDep)
>   + jour_nuit'

When I run an ols regression in `statsmodels` with this formula, I get main effects for the variable "Groupe", which I would like to avoid. 
I tried to add -1 in the formula (as suggested in the above mentioned discussion), but still get the main effects.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: According to the accepted answer in the referenced question, `C(MoisAvantDep)*C(Groupe) - C(Groupe)`  should work for removing the "Groupe" main effect

Comment: Yes it works, but then the main effect for MoisAvantDep remains, and I would like to get rid of both main effects .. I tried C(MoisAvantDep)*C(Groupe) - C(Groupe) - C(MoisAvantDep), but the main effect for MoisAvantDep remains. Thanks though.

Comment: It's not clear to me what columns you exactly want. Do you want the full set of interaction terms or the interaction terms without reference categories? If you want the former, then I think it's still not possible if there are more than two categorical variables, since the design matrix would be singular with redundant terms.

Comment: I agree with you. I would like interaction terms without reference categories and no main effetcs.

Comment: Ok, then I don't even know if that's possible. I never tried to have a model like that. Hopefully, someone can answer, I'm also interested.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me just add that softwares like Stata do not report main effects (when they are not asked for). The solution simply consists in dropping one of the interactions between the modalities of the categorical variables.