# Difference between the interaction : and * term for formulas in StatsModels OLS regression

Tags: python, statistics, regression, statsmodels

Hi I'm learning Statsmodel and can't figure out the difference between : and * (interaction terms) for formulas in StatsModels OLS regression. Could you please give me a hint to figure this out?

Thank you!

The documentation:
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html

Comment: The most complete explanation is in the patsy documentation http://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/formulas.html which is used by statsmodels. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672466/interaction-effects-in-patsy-with-patsy-dmatrices-giving-duplicate-columns-for also has some explanation for the difference between `:` and `*`.

Answer (score 26):

":" will give a regression **without** the level itself. just the interaction you have mentioned.

"*" will give a regression **with** the level itself + the interaction you have mentioned.

for example

**a**. `GLMmodel = glm("y ~  a: b"  , data = df)`

you'll have only one independent variable which is the results of "a" multiply    by "b"

**b**. `GLMmodel = glm("y ~  a * b"  , data = df)`

you'll have 3 independent variables which is the results of "a" multiply by "b"
+ "a" itself + "b" itself

Answer (score 5):

Using `A*B` is really just shorthand for `A + B + A:B`

`A:B` specifies the interaction itself. This is literally the product of the two variables. As such, it rarely makes sense to fit a model with only this term, so we almost always fit the main effects, `A` and `B` too (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27724/do-all-interactions-terms-need-their-individual-terms-in-regression-model) for reasons why). Since this is so common, the shorthand notation `A*B` for this is quite common in many statistical software packages/platforms.