# How to increase the impact of an explanatory variable on Y as we step forward in time?

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

**The question:**

I'm building a model on three time series where Y is the dependent variable, and X1 and X2 ar the explanatory variables. Let's say that there is strong reason to believe that the impact of X1 on Y increases compared to X2 as time goes by. How can you account for this in a multiple regression model?
(I'll show some code snippets as my question progresses, and you'll find a complete code section at the end.)

**The details - a visual approach:**

Here are three synthetic series  where it seems that the impact of X1 on Y is very strong at the end of the period:

[image]

**A basic model could be:**

```
model = smf.ols(formula='Y ~ X1 + X2')
```

And if you plot the fitted values against the observed Y values, you'd get this:

[image]

And sticking to a visual evaluation of the model, it seems that it performs OK in the majority of the period, but very poorly after August sets in.
How can I account for this in a multiple regression model? With the help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050104/difference-between-the-interaction-and-term-for-formulas-in-statsmodels-ols) I've tried to introduce an interaction term with both a linear and squared timestep in these models:

```
mod_timestep  = Y ~ X1 + X2:timestep
mod_timestep2 = Y ~ X1 + X2:timestep2
```

By the way, these are the timesteps:

[image]

[image]

**Results:**

[image]

It seems that both approaches perform a bit better in the end, but considerably worse in the beginning.

Any other suggestions? I know there's a multitude of possibilites with lagged terms of the dependent model and other models such as ARIMA or GARCH. But for a number of reasons I'd like to remain within the boundaries of multiple linear regressions and no lagged terms if possible.

Here's the whole thing for an easy copy&paste:

```
#%%
# imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

###############################################################################
# Synthetic Data and plot
###############################################################################

# Function to build synthetic data
def sample():

    np.random.seed(26)
    date = pd.to_datetime("1st of Dec, 1999")

    nPeriod = 250

    dates = date+pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(nPeriod), 'D')
    #ppt = np.random.rand(1900)
    Y = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=nPeriod).cumsum()
    X1 = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=nPeriod).cumsum()
    X2 = np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=nPeriod).cumsum()

    df = pd.DataFrame({'Y':Y,
                       'X1':X1,
                       'X2':X2},index=dates)
    # Adjust level of series
    df = df+100

    # A subset
    df = df.tail(50)
    return(df)

# Function to make a couple of plots
def plot1(df, names, colors):

    # PLot
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.set_facecolor('white')

    # Plot series
    counter = 0

    for name in names:
        print(name)
        ax.plot(df.index,df[name], lw=0.5, color = colors[counter])
        counter = counter + 1

    fig = ax.get_figure()

    # Assign months to X axis
    locator = mdates.MonthLocator()  # every month

    # Specify the X format
    fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b')
    X = plt.gca().xaxis
    X.set_major_locator(locator)
    X.set_major_formatter(fmt)
    ax.legend(loc = 'upper left', fontsize ='x-small')
    fig.show()

# Build sample data
df = sample()

# PLot of input variables
plot1(df = df, names = ['Y', 'X1', 'X2'], colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'])

###############################################################################
# Models
###############################################################################

# Add timesteps to original df
timestep = pd.Series(np.arange(1, len(df)+1), index = df.index)
timestep2 = timestep**2
newcols2 = list(df)
df = pd.concat([df, timestep, timestep2], axis = 1)

newcols2.extend(['timestep', 'timestep2'])
df.columns = newcols2

def add_models_to_df(df, models, modelNames):

    df_temp = df.copy()

    counter = 0
    for model in models:
        df_temp[modelNames[counter]] = smf.ols(formula=model, data=df).fit().fittedvalues
        counter = counter + 1

    return(df_temp)

df_models = add_models_to_df(df, models = ['Y ~ X1 + X2', 'Y ~ X1 + X2:timestep', 'Y ~ X1 + X2:timestep2'],
                             modelNames = ['mod_regular', 'mod_timestep', 'mod_timestep2'])


# Models
df_models = add_models_to_df(df, models = ['Y ~ X1 + X2', 'Y ~ X1 + X2:timestep', 'Y ~ X1 + X2:timestep2'],
                             modelNames = ['mod_regular', 'mod_timestep', 'mod_timestep2'])

# Plots of models
plot1(df = df_models,
      names = ['Y', 'mod_regular', 'mod_timestep', 'mod_timestep2'],
      colors = ['red', 'black', 'green', 'grey'])
```

### Edit 1 - screenshot from suggestion:**

[image]

Comment: I made a 3D scatterplot of X1, X2, and Y. After rotating the view around in 3-space, the data appears to be a "point cloud" with no visually obvious relationship to be modeled as "Y = f(X1, X2)" - which makes sense the way that sample() is coded using np,random. It may be of some use to perform this exercise on the original data to see if any obvious 3D relationship is apparent.

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you want to have more weightage(importance) to the recent observations(X1) ?

Comment: @asimo.Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: This can be dealt by feature engineering; by computing a variable that lists the time(days) elapsed from your start or end date. 
You can then apply a simple exponential function as W=K*exp(-timeElapsed/T), where K is a scaling constant and T is the time-constant for the decay function. W works as case-weight.
Now you can incorporate this new feature engineered variable as your new X1

Comment: @vestland Please let us know if this above suggested approach of coming up with a exponential function solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Using the other options on the link you provided would seem to be the better option.

Using your functions with `Y ~ X1 + X2*timestep` and `Y ~ X1 + X2*timestep2` will at least "catch" the increase in `Y` in the beginning, the decrease in the middle of the period and the sudden increase in the end.

I can't post images yet, so you'll have to try yourself.